# Subset a bs4.element.ResultSet by string match

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to reference a certain unnamed `<p>` Paragraph in html. I have identified the correct `<div>`, which is stored in `res`.

What I would like to do now is: Find the `<p>` which `<span>` contains the word "Country" and receive the value (here="Germany") as a character. Position matching doesn't work unfortunately, since position changes over pages.

```py
res = res.find(name="div", attrs={"class": "item-result-text"}).find_all(name="p")
print(res)
```

Result:

```
[<p><span>Country: </span>Germany</p>, <p><span>Coly: </span> Print</p>]
```

```py
print(type(res))
```

Result: `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do this in a different way though. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for

```
In [5]: a = "<p><span>Country: </span>Germany</p>, <p><span>Coly: </span> Print</p>"
In [6]: soup = BeautifulSoup(a,"lxml")
In [14]: values = {i.text.strip().split(":")[0].strip():i.text.strip().split(":")[1].strip() for i in soup.find_all("p")}

In [15]: values["Country"]
Out[15]: 'Germany'
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a very neat solution I am going to bookmark. I solved it in the meantime by chance with
`soup.find('span', text=re.compile("^Country")).next_sibling.string`